# Android OnItemClick not working with loaded SQL Database into listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview that is being populated from a sql database. The listview is under a fragment. My database contains three items

- ID
- PHONE NAME
- PHONE NUMBER

where I am trying to extract the phone name from the listview and show it in the toast display function in Android as a starting point, but when I try to use onItemClick to get the phone name from the listview, it's completely ignoring it and not executing.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_modem, container, false);
        btn_add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        // Display list setup
        display_contacts1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_contacts);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, display_contacts);
        display_contacts1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        // Database Setup
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        dbHelper = new DataDBAdapter(getActivity());
        dbHelper.open();

        // Add the data
        dbHelper.insertSomeValues();

        // Generate Listview from SQL Lite database
        displayListView();

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK);
            }
        });

// This part is not working 
            display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id)
                {

                    Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor)SelectModemFragment.display_contacts1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String NAME = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.KEY_PHONE_NAME));
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your are trying to cast a String to a Cursor in the line :-

```
Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor)SelectModemFragment.display_contacts1.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

That is, the item at the clicked position would appear to be a String as per `final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, display_contacts);`

I believe that instead you want to use

```
String NAME = (String) SelectModemFragment.display_contacts1.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

## Re comment

> I put in the line String NAME = (String)
>   SelectModemFragment.display_contacts1.getItemAtPosition(position);
>   under onItemClick as you said but still having no luck

The following is working code that very much replicates what you appear to be attempting:-

```
public class SelectModemFragment extends Fragment {

    private SelectModemViewModel mViewModel;
    ListView display_contacts1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> thelist;
    DataDBAdapter dbhelper;

    public static SelectModemFragment newInstance() {
        return new SelectModemFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_modem_fragment, container, false);
        display_contacts1 = view.findViewById(R.id.display_contacts1);

        dbhelper = new DataDBAdapter(view.getContext());
        AddSomeData();
        manageListView(view.getContext());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SelectModemViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

    //Sets up the ListView if not already setup
    private void manageListView(Context context) {
        thelist = dbhelper.getAllRowsAsList(); //<<<<<<<<<< extract the list (just the phone names) from the database

        // Only setup the adapter and the ListView if the adapter hasn't been setup
        if (arrayAdapter == null) {
            // Instantiate the adapter
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,thelist); //<<<<<<<<<< list included
            display_contacts1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //<<<<<<<<<< Tie the adpater to the ListView

            // Set the ListViews OnItemClick Listener
            display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String name = arrayAdapter.getItem(position); //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the phone name
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"You clicked the phone named " + name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    // Add some testing data (only if none already exists)
    private void AddSomeData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(dbhelper.getWritableDatabase(),DataDBAdapter.TBL_MYTABLE) < 1) {
            dbhelper.insert("Phone 1", "0000000000");
            dbhelper.insert("Phone 2", "1111111111");
        }
    }
}
```

In Case you want the Database Helper (DataDBAdapter.java) then it is :-

```
public class DataDBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBL_MYTABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME = "phonename";
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DataDBAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB  = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String mytable_crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_MYTABLE + "(" +
                COL_MYTABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(mytable_crt_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public long insert(String phonename, String phonenumber) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME,phonename);
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER,phonenumber);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_MYTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllRowsAsList() {
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME)));
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

## Result

The resultant App :-

[image]

*(you'll have to take my word that the Toast is displayed as expected)*

Comment: I put in the line String NAME = (String) SelectModemFragment.display_contacts1.getItemAtPosition(position); under onItemClick as you said but still having no luck

Comment: Did you remove the line `Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor)SelectModemFragment.display_contacts1.getItemAtPosition(position);` ?

Comment: Yes I removed it

Comment: I'll take your word that the toast is displaying as expected, I will use the code you have written and see my results. Cheers :)