# Listview not updating automatically even with notifyDataSetChanged() called with Sql database and Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursor

I'm using a function to select phone names from the android phone book and using a cursor to get the name and number of the contact. I am able to successfully do that and insert the values into the sqllite database that I have written with help from another question on here but the listview does not automatically update when there is a new value inserted to the database.

I've used all the lines required including

- `((BaseAdapter)display_contacts1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`
- `display_contacts1.invalidateViews();`
- `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
- `manageListView(getContext());`

But I am still having no luck finding a solution. The only way the listview will update is if I go into a different fragment or restart the app.

**Original SQL Database code**
[Android OnItemClick not working with loaded SQL Database into listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291966/android-onitemclick-not-working-with-loaded-sql-database-into-listview/55292395?noredirect=1#comment97313695_55292395)

**SelectModemFragment.java**

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Select Phone number from Contacts list
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Check for the request code
        switch (reqCode)
        {
            case CONTACT_PICKER:
                contactPicked(data);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("MainActiivity", "Failed to pick contact");
    }
}



private void contactPicked(Intent data)
{
    //Cursor cursor = null;
    try
    {
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // column index of the contact name
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);

        // Show message displaying the contact selected from the phonebook
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Insert values to sqlite database
        dbHelper.insert(name, phoneNo);

        // Need to immediately update the listview one the values have been inserted into the database
        ((BaseAdapter)display_contacts1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

        //display_contacts1.invalidateViews(); // This isn't working
        //arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // This isn't working
        //manageListView(getContext());, this didn't work
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the line thelist = dbHelper.getAllRowsAsList(); and ((BaseAdapter)display_contacts1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); after inserting the values into the database but still did not automatically update the listview

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the values into the database you can still call notifyDataSetChanged() and then just open the fragment again

```
 // Need to immediately update the listview one the values have been inserted into the database
            ((BaseAdapter)display_contacts1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Reopen the fragment
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, SelectModemFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```